# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'display' in python

Tags: python-3.x, module, pip

I have already installed 'display' module for python using the following code:

`pip3 install display`

However,
when I try to import a module with the code given below,

`from display import Displayable`

I get the following error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'display'`

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module is not widely used and does not have proper documentation.
I suggest using `pprint` to display data nicely.
Start by pip installing `pprint`:

#### Windows:

`pip install pprint36`

#### Mac:

`pip3 install pprint36`

### Code

```
import pprint
stuff = [['apple', 'bannana'],'spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights', 'ni']
stuff.insert(0, stuff[:])
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4,compact=False)
pp.pprint(stuff)
```

> From pprint docs